# Apagar elemento de um array de strings no mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Olá.

Quero apagar um elemento de um array de string, no caso é o array Profiles, que esta presente no Documento Person.

Isto numa aplicação desenvolvida em .net e com mongodb driver.

Exemplo de um documento na coleção:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e285ff7ac033a913ca37a0c"},"PersonId":{"$numberInt":"7"},"Profiles":["profile1","profile2","profile3"],"CreatedDate":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1579703399301"}},"UpdatedDate":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1579703399301"}}}
```

E o código para remover do array em c#:

```
  var update = Builders<Person>.Update.PullFilter(
        c => c.Profiles,
        s => s == "profile1");

    await this.DBset.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(c => c.PersonId == personId, update).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Está a ser retornado o seguinte erro:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: '{document} is not supported.'
MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
    MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType, System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression)
    MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
    MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerRegistry)
    MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl<TDocument>.UsingImplicitSessionAsync<TResult>(System.Func<MongoDB.Driver.IClientSessionHandle, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

Alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituindo o `PullFilter` por `Pull` deve resultar.

```cs
var update = Builders<Person>.Update.Pull(c => c.Profiles, "profile1");

await this.DBset.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(c => c.PersonId == personId, update).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

PS: Caso não seja necessário obter o resultado da query, pode alterar também de `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` para `UpdateOneAsync`.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou.